# How to insert double in an array[][]?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to insert doubles in an array (D[i][j]=distance;) but I get this error: Array required but double found!! I can't see my mistake!! plz help
This is the code:

```
 public static double[] D=new double[1000];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Data points matrice: X
    double X[][] = { {0.5,0.3,0.25,0.4},
                     {0.4,0.33,0.26,0.7},
                     {0.1,0.9,0.34,0.77},
                     {0.1,0.98,0.28,0.4},
                     {0.75,0.63,0.51,0.6}};

    for (int i=0; i<X.length-1;i++){ 
        for (int z=0; z<X.length; z++){
            double d=0;
            for (int j=0; j<X[i].length;j++){
                   if (i!=z){

                   System.out.println(X[i][j]+"et"+X[z][j]);  
                   d=d+Math.pow((X[i][j]-X[z][j]),2);
                   }else {d=0;}   

                   System.out.println(d);  
                   double distance= Math.sqrt(d);
                   D[i][j]=distance;

            }   
        System.out.println("*****"); 

        }
```

Comment: `D` is only a 1D `Array`. `D[i]` returns a double, and so `D[i][j]` is invalid

Comment: `public static double[][] D = new double[1000][1000];` ?

Comment: thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the declaration of `D` to the following:

```
public static double[][] D = new double[5][5];
```

This makes `D` a two-dimensional array rather than one-dimensional.